# What is the difference between bool? MyProperty and bool ?MyProperty

Tags: c#

While reviewing a PR today I saw this in a class:

```
public bool ?Selected { get; set; }   //question mark in front of property name
```

I suspected that the developer meant this

```
public bool? Selected { get; set; }  //question mark at end of type
```

I was surprised that this even complied so I tried it myself and found that this is legal code and it ends up doing the same thing.

My question is: Is there any subtle (or not so subtle) difference between these two?

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: One is really ugly

Comment: What I am most curious about is why this is legal syntax, it just looks wrong and confusing to me.

Comment: It s like int* a and int *a in c++

Comment: Thanks for comments.  I am going to have them change it to the more common bool? so that it's consistent with the rest of the code.  This caught me off guard!

Comment: @HitLikeAHammer in the default VS setup, `CTRL-K CTRL-D` will auto-format the current document.  If it doesn't work your key bindings might be configured differently.

Comment: @sTrenat, c++ can be more misleading. `int? a, b` declares 2 nullable int in c#, `int* a, b` (or `int *a, b`) declares a pointer and an integer

Comment: @sTrenat: Gian Paolo's comment indicates that the preferred syntax for C++ should be `int *a, b;`, because this gives us the intuitive understanding that expressions `*a` and `b` are both *variables of type int*.  By contrast, in unsafe C#, `int* a, b;` gives you the understanding that `a` and `b` are both *variables of type `int*`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, my Visual Studio 2017 immediately corrects this

```
public bool ?Selected { get; set; }
```

To this

```
public bool? Selected { get; set; }
```

Then, [IL DASM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387(v=vs.71).aspx) to the rescue! You can see that **the resulting IL is the same**, just like @mjwills said in the comments:

[image]

[image]

In the end, you can always hit <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd></kbd> + <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd></kbd> to have Visual Studio reformat your code and properly manage blanks and indentation.

As per your question about changing `bool?` to `bool`, it depends: if something can have an [indefinite value or state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204408/what-is-the-use-of-nullablebool-type), just like [checkboxes](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/10/use-a-tristate-checkbox-in-c/), you should use `bool?`; otherwise `bool` is fine.

Comment: I'll vote up just because you went so far to do all this research.

Comment: Thanks for the work though, to clarify, my question is not about changing bool? to bool.  It is only about the placement of the question mark.

Answer (score 1):

It might make a little more sense when you realize that the following is also valid:

```
public bool?Selected { get; set; }
```

`?` in that context is the nullable type identifier and as such it can't be followed by any character that would make sense in the current token, so the lexer simply processes the nullable type identifier and starts lexing the following expected token. Whats really redundant is the whitespace, its more a format helper to make it more readable than a syntax requirement.

Whitespaces are in many contexts meaningless trivia the compiler could do without.

Its similar in a sense as to why the following are all valid:

```
static bool Huh<T >() { return false; }
static bool Huh<T > () { return false; }
static bool Huh <T > () { return false; }
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, there is no difference in how the code functions based on the location of ?. The compiler doesn't much care for whitespace assuming it can make out the operators and operands. It simply comes down to readability and personal/team preference.

For example, given:

```
var app = new App();
```

These are also the same:

```
app.      SomeMethod();
```

And

```
app      .SomeMethod();
```

And

```
app   .   SomeMethod();
```

Or placing the dot operator anywhere else inbetween; including on a new line. It all compiles down to the same IL.